# How to reuse view in NavigationView when using with NavigationLink?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, swiftui, appdelegate

I have a simple macOS application written on **Swift** + **Swift UI** + **AppDelegate LifeCycle**.

I want to use **NavigationView** to have left sidebar in my application.
Everything is fine, but when I'm switching between views in NavigationView - *they are getting reinitialized each time I click on **NavigationLink***.

You can see it in my GIF below. I added *arc4random()* function to the Text on each view and when I'm going to the next view and back - value in Text changes. It tells me that my views are reinitialized.

[What I have now: [Image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vzmsc.gif)

I don't want to save that pseudo generated random value in variable, I just want to make **NavigationLink** not to reinitialize views. I want to reuse them *(with previous saved state: i.e. scroll position, elements in list and other)*.
Because each time I switch between views in **NavigationView** -  RAM usage increases +0.1MB.
*Yes, its not a lot at all, but I don't think that it is normal.*

```
import SwiftUI

//Dummy View #1
struct HelloWorldView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("This is HelloWorld View --> \(arc4random())").bold()
    }
}

//Dummy View #2
struct GoodbyeWorldView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("This is GoodbyeWorldView \(arc4random())").bold()
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

@State private var selection: String?

var body: some View {
    
    NavigationView {
        List (selection: $selection) {
            Section(header: Text("Top")) {
                
                NavigationLink(destination: HelloWorldView()) {
                    Text("First")
                }
                
                NavigationLink(destination: GoodbyeWorldView()) {
                    Text("Second")
                }
                
            }
            
        }.listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
        
        
    }
    
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

[What I want to have (Example): [Image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijbpo.gif)

So how to reuse the previous state of my view?

Comment: Hi welcome to SO. Watch this. It may shed some light on what you are seeing. https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10022/

Answer (score 0):

SwiftUI does not offer a lot of customization. You could simply ZStack your views and change opacity.